# How to access Apollo Result Object within VueJs3

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, apollo

I'm brand new to using Vue-Apollo, and I'm having some confusion with how to access the retuerned data within Apollos result object within my Vue Template.

VueComponent.js

```
    const store = useCaseFileStore();
    
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
    
    const FILE_QUERY = gql`
      query File($term: String!) {
        lookupFile(term: $term) {
          id
          author
          city
          state
        }
      }
    `;
    const term = "101707058976";
    const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(FILE_QUERY, {
      term,
    })

    const cities = console.log(result.cities)
    ;
```

However the final const returns undefined, despite seeing the data within Vue Dev Tools.